# How to split training data and testing data by account(one variable)

Tags: python, split, logistic-regression

I'm trying to fit logistic regression. I want to split training and testing data by account (a variable that doesn't play a role into fitting). I want them to be split by account, and each account can have lots of variables. For example, 80% of the account will be training, 20% account will be testing.

I've tried the following, but this code just give me 80% training and 20% testing randomly. Then in training data, it will give me some account, but in testing data, it will also give me that exactly account just with different variables. That's not what I want.

X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.20,random_state=0)

Please advise. Thank you!

Comment: Can I modify the code this way? X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.20,random_state=0, stratify = account)

Comment: `each account can have lots of variables` - what does this mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this

```
import numpy as np

def group_train_test_split(X, y, test_size, random_state, stratify):
    X = X.copy()
    X['_target'] = y

    X = X.set_index(stratify)
    index = X.index

    index_values = index.unique().values
    np.random.seed(random_state)
    np.random.shuffle(index_values)

    cut = np.round(index_values.shape[0] * test_size).astype('<i4')

    X_test, X_train = X.loc[index_values[:cut]], X.loc[index_values[cut:]]

    return X_test['_target'], X_train['_target'], X_test.drop('_target', axis=1), X_train.drop('_target', axis=1)

y_test, y_train, X_test, X_train = group_train_test_split(X=X, y=y, test_size=0.2, random_state=41, stratify='account')
```

This way it will take 20% of the accounts into test data, while the rest will be in the training data.

Comment: Thank you so much! However, I don't quite get the code. Can you assume that X is a data frame that contain all the 10 variables plus account (regardless the length), and y is a data frame that contain binary outcome. Can you please modify your code based on my data?

Comment: I've just updated the code with more explanation and handling of the target variable as well. Does it make more sense now?

Comment: Thanks so much for that. I'm just a beginner to Python, so this code still doesn't make sense to me. Can you please assume that my X contain 10 variables and account? I'm expecting a few lines of code. For example, I'm thinking X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.20,random_state=0, stratify = X['account'])

Comment: Couldn't really find anything already implemented for your use-case. So I've reformatted the code.

Comment: Thank you so much! The code works, except that the result: y_test and y_train contain one column of account and one column of NaN (it should be 0 and 1). I believe the code doesn't separate X_test['_target'], X_train['_target'] well. Can you please modify the code?

Comment: You are absolutely right, there was a bug. Actually there were 2 bugs, the random_state was useless before, it is useful now. Let me know if these last changes worked.

Comment: This works perfect, thank you so much for everything!